# What's the difference between [tags] and [tagging]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging, meta

What's the difference between the [[tagging](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tagging)] and [[tags](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tags)] tags?  Are they similar enough that we shouldn't have both?

Comment: do moderator powers include ability to make tag synonyms?

Comment: @Grigory M: Yes, we can forcibly create tag synonyms without having to go through the vote process.  (Users with 1000 rep or more can suggest and vote on tag synonyms.)

Comment: @Grigory, @Isaac: Tag synonyms are not the same as tag merging. Tag merging affects the past, modifying tags on existing questions. Tag synonyms affect the future, so that all questions that users mark with "[tags]" will instead get tagged `tagging`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we should merge them, obviously.